# Does array resizing invoke the GC?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, garbage-collection, xna

I looked into the implementation of Array.Resize() and noticed that a new array is created and returned. I'm aiming for zero memory allocation during gameplay and so I need to avoid creating any new reference types. Does resizing an array trigger the Garbage Collector on the previous array? I'm creating my own 2D array resizer, but it essentially functions in the same way as the .NET `Resize()` method.

If the new array is smaller than the previous one, but excess objects have already been placed back into a generic object pool, will this invoke the GC?

Arrays will constantly be created in my game loop, so I need to try and make it as efficient as possible. I'm trying to create an `array pool` as such, so that there's no need to keep creating them ingame. However, if the resize method does the same thing, then it makes little sense to not just instantiate a new array instead of having the pool.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe you could use `List<T>` that is basically an automatic resized array, and I guess when you reduce it, it doesn't reduce the array immediately... mmh I have to check...

Comment: @digEmAll: `List<T>` uses `T[]` internally but does the resizing for you. In other words: it will create new instances.

Comment: Thanks for the suggetsion. A List of a List crossed my mind (as I'm using 2D arrays) but it's slightly more convoluted for my game.

Comment: @Brian: yes of course, but IIRC it doesn't resize at every insertion/deletion, but in some manner avoid too many resizings i.e. new instances. (it doubles the size at each insertion that requires more space than the available or something similar...)

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to have no memory allocation?

Comment: It's not a hard and fast rule, but the game will be running on a portable device and arrays are being created and, until a redesign, destroyed multiple times (approx every 3-4 seconds) in a 30 FPS game. This over a certain time period will no doubt invoke the GC and I'm worried that the GC may cause the framerate to drop. It may be temporary, but a frame drop is a frame drop. Added to that, the array creation is not the only dynamic aspect in the game, so if I can minimise on all fronts, the better...

Comment: ..Of course, this may be a micro-optimization, but I'm aware when the GC hits on the phone and it will no doubt be unfriendly to the battery on such a scale.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Array.Resize` doesn't actually change the original array at all - anyone who still has a reference to it will be able to use it as before. Therefore there's no optimization possible. Frankly it's a badly named method, IMO :(

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ffy6686(v=VS.80).aspx):

> This method allocates a new array with
>   the specified size, copies elements
>   from the old array to the new one, and
>   then replaces the old array with the
>   new one.

So no, it's not going to reuse the original memory or anything like that. It's just creating a shallow copy with a different size.

Comment: That's a good point. It would have been better to accept the original by value and return the new one. The whole passing by reference here could really confuse a junior programmer in this case.

Comment: I was going through the method in Reflector and it just didn't sit right when I saw a new array being created. I guess I'm going to have to come to a compromise regarding the design, and carry out a few performance tests. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: +1 for reminding us that, even if the GC heap has adjacent unallocated 'free' space available immediately above the existing array, the possibility of other handle holders semantically precludes changing the size of the existing array. This implies that `Resize` *could* be *in-situ* optimized *iff* the GC can prove that the submitted handle is the last/only reference. However, despite being less-rigorously incorrect, doing so at this point would now be a *breaking change* for existing apps that depend on the assumption that the original vs. resized instance have distinct reference identities.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `Array.Resize` causes a new array to be allocated and the old one to eventually be collected (unless there are still references to it somewhere).

A more low-level array resizer could possibly do some minor optimization in some cases (for example when the array is being made smaller or there happens to be memory available right after the array), but .NET's implementation doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly yes.

Explicitly no.

Answer (score 1):

Any allocation will eventually be cleaned up by the GC when no more references exist, so yes.

If you want to avoid resizing your arrays, the best thing you could do would be to preallocate with a large enough size to avoid having to reallocate at all. In that case, you might as well just use a collection class with an initial capacity specified in the constructor, such as List.